# Spring boot files uploaded dynamically not showing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, image-uploading

I'm making a Spring boot application, one of its functions is uploading images dynamically, after uploading the image the user is redirected to his profile page and the image shows there as the profile image. The problem I'm having is that the image, even if its uploaded and is inside the folder it should be, doesn't show when I log the image. I managed to show the image refreshing the project via eclipse (f5), but when I'm deploying the application in a JAR file it just doesn't show and I'm not sure what to do. It's like if Spring boot is not able to know that image is there...

Not sure how to fix this, any ideas?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds like a http caching problem.  The picture shows up if you do an f5 on the browser?  Is the image the same name?  Some things you could try, Easiest is to change the name of the image.  If you have to keep the name of the image, try and change the cache setting of the image.  You can verify if the image is being cached by using a browser's developer tools and looking at the headers of the image response or use a browser plugin like HttpHeaders.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show even if I use f5 on browser, it just does if I use f5 in Eclipse project (It's really strange).

Comment: That is absolutely strange.  I do not have any other ideas at this point, hopefully someone else will be along to help.  My best advice right now is to try and run through the debugger and see if anything looks out of the ordinary.  Best of luck.

Comment: I somehow 'fixed' (not really) now im deplying the app from a traditional tomcat server... and it works. Anyways id like to know why it doesnt in normal .jar or in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in the Helper file.

```java
public final String UPLOAD_DIR = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/image").toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I changed the packaging from jar to war. It worked perfectly for me.

In pom.xml, inside project tag, I placed following line

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```